# Does using 'delete' like this free up the original allocated memory?

Tags: c++

```
class A {
    struct structA;
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
structA* structAPointer = new structA;
```

A land far far away:

```
void Wonderland::rabbitHole(structA* structAPointer) {
    delete structAPointer;
}
```

Does the delete operator free up the original memory allocated in 'Somewhere else'?

Comment: If `rabbitHole` is being called with the original `structAPointer`, yes.

Comment: @Jeffrey Shouldn't the pointer be passed by reference for that to happen?

Comment: @0x499602D2, not really. The `delete` operator frees up the memory address, not the variable that holds it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't matter what part of the code allocated it delete will `delete` anything created by `new`

while `delete []` is for things created by `new []`.

However usually you want the part that created it to be responsible for deleting it , to make managing memory easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the delete operator free up the original memory allocated in 'Somewhere else'?

Yes, **if** the *original* `structAPointer` has never been modified and is being passed to `rabbitHole`.

The `delete` operator works on the value (address) of the variable that holds the pointer so there's really anything stopping you to use `rabbitHole` on any `structA*` you have dinamically allocated.

It is to say, though, that using `new` and `delete` (or `new[]` and `delete[]` for that matter) is highly discouraged by the *C++ community*. There are [a lot of alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to handle dynamically allocated memory that are proven to work better. For example the `std` library holds a [very good set of utilities](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/) to help you manage dynamic memory without the cons of handling the pointers yourself.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how people normally do things? I've only been coding as a hobby and don't really know the 'standard' approach to managing memory.

Comment: @Hobbyist, there multiple type of smart pointers provided by the std library. Their use really depends on the context of your application. The wikipedia link I put in the answer contains a brief explanation of the difference. For anything else take a look at the other link to the cpp reference website.

Comment: If I wanted to pass a pointer created in a chain of functions through several other functions and have it destroyed only at the end of the chain of functions, what pointer would you suggest that I use?

Comment: @Hobbyist, possibly a `std::shared_ptr`.